# Unable to access angular services from nativescript worker

Tags: angular, multithreading, nativescript

I am following this tutorial for creating a background threading, 
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model#workers-api

This works for simple cases, but then I have 
app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        LoginModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        HttpService,
        UserService,
        LogService,
        DatabaseService
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

How can I use service like UserService inside w.onmessage() , without using dependency injection. Or how to use a injectable class with w.onmessage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. NS workers run in a completely different context and there is no shared memory.

I'd recommend using workers mainly to process heavy data and send it back to the main thread. The only other options are dependency injection and duplicating code.

Comment: Does that mean, I simply replace current UserService.ts(thats added in the app.module.ts) and instead create a normal (non injectable) new service file and import-instantiate all the required dependencies (Http, dbService) manually ? Can I simple use the same UserService from the worker file.

Comment: You can't use the same UserService. You either instantiate a new UserService by using `Injector.create`, use things non-angular style, or simply comunicate with postmessage. May I ask why do you want to use UserService inside a worker?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, makes more sense now..
Here is the situation,
I had been using UserService to fetch & update users (this happens in a certain interval again), while this process takes around 2-3 mins, in which case I just had to block the UI. So, thinking of moving it to worker so that the process runs in background and not disturb the UI. and turns out worker works in different way than the angular flow.

Comment: here's what you can do: make an HTTP request using UserService to get a bunch of data (this doesn't block the UI). Send this data via postmessage to the worker and process it. When done, send the processed data back and use it in your application. We have a similar use case: we get a lot of data from a webservice, send it to our worker which stores it in a sqlite and returns when done. We then make sqlite queries (<1ms) to fetch/filter the data we need.